# Team city Build config fire another team city config without it being a dependency

Tags: teamcity

I have a team city config (Int_Build) that builds my integration branch and displays results once its successful in a code review tool. I want that another team city config to be fired that will build and run a rest suite and mail all developers. I can not add a dependency as I don't want the test suite results mail to effect the integration display results success. I can not use VCS Root for triggers as there are multiple test suite Build configs. Is it possible to have a trigger to the test suite Build config once Int_Build is done. It should be kind of a one way dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [Finish Build Trigger](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger).

You can configure it in "test suite" build configuration settings (`Triggers` section) to trigger once  "Int_Build" is done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I ended up using a curl command to add a job in the test suite.